# limit script self run more than 6 times in python

Tags: python

i have a script that check some server processes. called `worker.py`

i have it running on crontab once per minute ( its crucial )

normaly my code works in 5 minutes then i have 5 workers running at same time.

some time one or more workers runs ins 10 or more minutes by doing diferent pre configured routines.

but if i have more than10 workers in memory my server crashes.

i tryed to use singleton from python but it cant help me.

some one knows how to limit the execution os theses workers  if some new worker wuns it will count how many of then are running and exit() if there are 6 or more?

im doing a subprocess function in comando line

```
ps -A | grep pythonrules.py | wc -l
```

but i want a more pythonic way to do that.

Comment: It would be way easier to check the number of running instances from shell. Maybe just put something like this in crontab: `(($(ps -ef | grep worker.py | wc -l) < 6)) && python worker.py`?

Comment: id like to control it in python becouse im using continuous delivery to update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?
You'd need to install `psutil` with `pip` but it's a pretty "standard" package.

```py
import sys

import psutil

# variant (1), using a for loop
count = 0
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if "pythonrules.py" in "".join(p.cmdline()):
        count += 1

# variant (2), using a generator comprehension
count = sum(
    1
    for p
    in psutil.process_iter()
    if "pythonrules.py" in "".join(p.cmdline())
)

if count >= 6:
    sys.exit(0)
```